# Why Topshelf called "Start" method again while Windows Service was already running?

Tags: restart, topshelf

i am facing a scenario like, I started windows service and at some point, some database connectivity issues came (due to some network prob). Topshelf called the `Start` method again while windows service was already running & it didn't call `Stop` method before calling `Start` again (i came to know of this thing by reading logs because i log some text in "Start" method)

I don't want Topshelf to call Start method multiple times.
Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Topshelf should only call your delegate for `WhenStarted` when the Service Control Manager requests a start. If you see start being called more than once, is your service crashing and restarting? Are you running multiple instances of your service somehow? Are you sure it's the `WhenStarted` delegate that's being called?

Comment: There were some network related issues and service was trying to access database and was not able to connect. Suddenly it called the start method again (Delegate for **WhenStarted**), i think it crashed after trying many times to connect to Database

Comment: any suggestion, how we can prevent `Top Shelf` from crashing and calling `Start` method again ?

Comment: If you catch your exceptions instead of letting them bubble up, then your service won't restart. This isn't really a Topshelf problem at all, if you had a service without the Topshelf wrapper, I expect you'd see a similar behavior.